# CVCalendar: How to override CVCalendar properties that do not have explicit function API?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the library CVCalendar for Swift and I am trying to customize the appearance of the calendar. 
I have a ViewController called "FirstViewController" where the UIView for the Calendar is located.  In my file FirstViewController.swift I managed to implement the property customizations where CVCalendar provides a function as API.

But I don't know what is the correct way to **customize other properties which do not have these function APIs**. For example the CVCalendar's class [CVCalendarViewAppearanceDelegate](https://github.com/CVCalendar/CVCalendar/wiki/CVCalendarViewAppearanceDelegate) has many properties with default values that can be modified such as dayLabelWeekdayInTextColor.

**Question:**  How do I modify correctly a property like the "dayLabelWeekdayInTextColor from FirstViewController.swift?

Note that I created a function setupCalendarFormat() where I am modifying the properties; I tried calling it in viewDidLoad() and viewDidLayoutSubviews() but the modifications are not working correctly.

My code below:

```
import UIKit
import CVCalendar

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuView: CVCalendarMenuView!
    @IBOutlet weak var calendarView: CVCalendarView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        setupCalendarFormat()

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        //setupCalendarFormat()
        menuView.commitMenuViewUpdate()
        calendarView.commitCalendarViewUpdate()
    }


    func setupCalendarFormat(){

    //CircleView background color and alpha
    calendarView.appearance.dayLabelPresentWeekdayHighlightedBackgroundColor = UIColor.black //not working highlight color not changing to black

    //day numbers' color
    calendarView.appearance.dayLabelWeekdayInTextColor = UIColor.green // not working correctly, color is only changing to green after i select the number
    calendarView.appearance.dayLabelPresentWeekdayTextColor = UIColor.green // working , probably becuase by default the present day is selected

    }


}


extension FirstViewController: CVCalendarViewDelegate, CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate{


    //All these APIs are succesfully called
    func presentationMode() -> CalendarMode {
        return .weekView
    }

    func firstWeekday() -> Weekday {
        return .sunday
    }

    func dayOfWeekFont() -> UIFont {
        return UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .medium)
    }
    func dayOfWeekTextColor() -> UIColor { 
        return .black
    }

    func dayOfWeekTextUppercase() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func shouldShowWeekdaysOut() -> Bool { 
        return true
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "from my ViewController containing the Calendar View" means? "Containing" how exactly?

Comment: See my answer below; as a side note, for future questions try to use less chunks of pure text and add more structure to it so it is easier to understand, takes reviewers less time to quality-check it and is less likely to get close-voted.

Comment: @matt thank you, I added more details "I have a ViewController called "FirstViewController" where the UIView for the CVCalendar is located."

Comment: @Manuel thank you for the advise and reply, noted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CVCalendar` repository provides you with a `CVCalendar Demo` that demonstrates how to set the colors of the calendar elements.

It basically works like this:

1. Set a view controller as the delegate of the `CVCalendar`
2. Make the delegate conform to the delegate protocol
3. Add the delegate methods for setting the colors of the calendar element

When the calendar is about to display for example a text element, it asks its delegate (your view controller) for the color by calling the specific method that will - based on your logic - return a `UIColor`, e.g.:

```
extension ViewController: CVCalendarViewDelegate, CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate {

   func dayOfWeekTextColor(by weekday: Weekday) -> UIColor {
       return weekday == .sunday ? UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0) : UIColor.white
   }
}
```

See the [demo implementation](https://github.com/CVCalendar/CVCalendar/blob/e459d1258e0bdb56b06da1458709b874426367b2/CVCalendar%20Demo/CVCalendar%20Demo/ViewController.swift#L93).

Comment: Thank you for the reply Manuel. Sorry that I wasn't specific enough; All these properties that have an explicit API function such as "func dayOfWeekTextColor" are perfectly working. My question is how to modify the properties that do not have this kind of function. I added my code and more details in the question, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I am making you reply the correct answer because the key was in step two "Make the delegate conform to the delegate classes". That means making an extension ViewController: CVCalendarViewAppearanceDelegate. Once I did this I could find the missing methods such as "func dayLabelWeekdayInTextColor() -> UIColor"